# How to accumulate messages as mqtt client for 1 second, then save it to a file

Tags: python, mqtt, mosquitto, libmosquitto

my problem is as follows:
I wrote a program that subscribes to a topic, where 2 dictionaries with one key respectively arrive more times a second. On every message they change their value.
I save those dictionaries in a big buffer-dictionary called "Status". What I need is to save a "snapshot" of Status every second into a file.

I tried time.sleep(1) but it drifts. And I don't know how to handle the problem with a schedule due to the already existing client-loop...

I'm pretty new to python and mqtt and would appreciate your help

My code:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import time
import json

Status = {}

#create client instance
client = mqtt.Client(client_id=None, clean_session=True, transport="tcp")

#connect to broker
client.connect("my_broker", 1883)

#use subscribe() to subscribe to a topic and receive messages
client.subscribe("topic/#", qos=0)

def test1_callback(client, userdata, msg):
    msg_dict = json.loads((msg.payload))
    Status.update(msg_dict)

client.message_callback_add("topic/test1", test1_callback)

while True:
    client.loop_start()
    time.sleep(1)
    client.loop_stop()

    with open('Data.txt', 'a+') as file:
        t = time.localtime()
        Status["time"]= time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
            file.write(str(Status["time"]) + " ")
            file.write(str(Status["key1"]) + " ")
            file.write(str(Status["key2"]) + " ")

    client.loop_start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of manually stopping the networking thread I would prefer using a timer which fires every second. In addition it might be a good idea to lock the data when storing it to a file - otherwise there might occur an update in between:

```
# ...
import threading

def test1_callback(client, userdata, msg):
   msg_dict = json.loads((msg.payload))
   lock.acquire()
   Status.update(msg_dict)
   lock.release()

def timer_event():
   lock.acquire()
   # save to file here
   lock.release()
   # restart timer
   threading.Timer(1, timer_event).start()

Status = {}
lock = threading.Lock()

# client initialization
# ...

client.loop_start()
threading.Timer(1, timer_event).start()

while True:
   pass
```

But this won't prevent your stored value to drift away because the topic is apparently published too frequently so your subscriber (or even the broker) is not able to handle a message fast enough.

So you might want to reduce the interval in which this topic is published. Also notice that you subscribed to a multi-level topic - even if the topics besides `"topic/test1"` are not handled in your code they still cause load for the broker and the subscribing client